# Magento 2 admin product custom option page add customer group dropdown

Tags: magento2, product, custom-options, customer-group

I want to add customer group dropdown on product custom option page.
the reason behind is to show the custom option based on the customer group in front-end.

how can i achieve the above functionality.
Here with i have attached the screen which is what i need 
[image]

Kindly share your ideas and thoughts, thanks in advance for you support